# ruby 3.1.4 puma 5.6 prune_bundler loops with Early termination of worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

After upgrade to ruby 3.1.4 puma didn't start but loops with

```
+ Gemfile in context: .../releases/20230405083245/Gemfile
! Unable to start worker
.../shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:308:in `check_for_activated_spec!'
Early termination of worker
```

How can I make puma run again?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to fix this issue:

1. revert to ruby 3.1.2 (missing security fixes)
2. remove `prune_bundler` from config file (puma.rb)
   when starting, puma states `Restarts: (√) phased`, but I didn't check
3. upgrade puma (i.e. 6.2.1)

To upgrade puma, I first had to upgrade `capistrano-puma` to 6.0.0.beta.1.